# Running insert command that contains LongBlob via C# does not add new row into MySql table

Tags: c#, mysql

Within my MySQL database, I have a table that looks like this :-

```
Table Name = MessageImages                 
Column 1 = ImageID (Varchar(5)) NOT NULL        
Column 2 = FileSize (Int(11)) NOT NULL        
Column3 = Image (LongBlob) NOT NULL
```

I have written a method in C# that should insert new rows of data into this table. this method is:-

```
public void InsertBlob(String id, byte[] values)
{
    //'connection' is a global MySqlConnection variable
    try
    {
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO MessageImage(ImageID, FileSize, Image) VALUES(?ImageID,?FileSize,?Image)", connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ImageID", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?FileSize", values.Length);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Image", values);

            connection.Open();
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

The issue I have is that this is not adding the row into the database, even though the 'result' return from executing this command is '1'. Can anyone help me identify what is causing this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: why are you using `?` for your parameters, I do not use mySql but if it's anything like SqlServer you need to replace your `?` with `@` try that first also this is not needed `connection.Close();` inside your using() {}` this gets handled by auto-dispose within the using construct..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with '@' before I changed the code into what has been written here and that did not have the desired outcome.

Comment: Is it possible that there is an active transaction (started with `connection.BeginTransaction()`) that is never committed? If so, `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will still return 1, but the row won't actually be inserted when the transaction is (implicitly) rolled back.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger that's helped massively thank you. Took your advice and it's working like a charm.